Error Reading pubspec.yaml File in Flutter Project

I'm experiencing an issue while trying to read the pubspec.yaml file in my Flutter project. Here’s the situation:
I have the following Dart code to read the pubspec.yaml file:
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:yaml/yaml.dart'; // For reading YAML files

void main() async {
  // Specify the path to the pubspec.yaml file
  final filePath = '../pubspec.yaml'; // Update this according to your directory structure
  final file = File(filePath);

  // Check if the file exists
  if (await file.exists()) {
    // Read the file
    final String text = await file.readAsString();

    // Load the YAML content
    Map yaml = loadYaml(text);

    // Extract information from the YAML
    print('App Name: ${yaml['name']}');
    print('Description: ${yaml['description']}');
    print('Version: ${yaml['version']}');
    print('Author: ${yaml['author']}');
    print('Homepage: ${yaml['homepage']}');
    print('Dependencies: ${yaml['dependencies']}');
  } else {
    print('pubspec.yaml file not found: $filePath');
  }
}

When I run this code, I encounter the following error message:

Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone16k arm64 in debug mode... ✓
Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk Connecting to VM
Service at ws://127.0.0.1:61423/kakyQdOAGF0=/ws Connected to the VM
Service. I/flutter ( 4529): Current directory: / I/flutter ( 4529):
pubspec.yaml file not found at: pubspec.yaml I/.example.reader( 4529):
Compiler allocated 5250KB to compile void
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals() D/ProfileInstaller(
4529): Installing profile for com.example.reader

Problem Description
The error indicates that the Dart code cannot find the pubspec.yaml file at the specified path. The current working directory is shown as the root directory (/), but the file is not located there.
Request for Help
I am struggling to resolve this issue and would appreciate any suggestions or guidance from anyone who has faced a similar problem. What steps can I take to fix the pubspec.yaml file not found error? Any insights would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

How are your directories structured? Can you share a screenshot?

can you describe your folder structure ? where is your main located and where is your pubspec.yaml located?

@dipansh added image

@WalaAbdo added image
